# Given a sparse matrix with shape (num_samples, num_features), how do I estimate the co-occurrence matrix?

Tags: python, machine-learning, data-mining

The sparse matrix has only 0 and 1 at each entry `(i,j)` (1 stands for sample `i` has feature `j`). How can I estimate the co-occurrence matrix for each feature given this sparse representation of data points? Especially, I want to find pairs of features that co-occur in at least 50 samples. I realize it might be hard to produce the exact result, is there any approximated algorithm in data mining that allows me to do that?

Comment: Using numpy, you could use the numpy.where function. More info here: https://docs.scipy.org/doc/numpy/reference/generated/numpy.where.html

Answer (score 0):

This can be solved reasonably easily if you go to a transposed matrix.

Of any two features (now rows, originally columns) you compute the intersection. If it's larger than 50, you have a frequent cooccurrence.

If you use an appropriate sparse encoding (now of rows, but originally of columns - so you probably need not only to transpose the matrix, but also to reencode it) this operation using O(n+m), where n and m are the number of nonzero values.

If you have an extremely high number of features this make take a while. But 100000 should be feasible.